# After getting intent value from fragment how can i implement in recyclerview item click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I set a  button in recyclerview itemclick , After clicking button fragment will be open ,and I get the fragment value perfectly and pass that value through intent ,but my problem is  how can I implement get extra intent in recyclerview adapter and set value to that particular itemclick. Please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

> Pass Data From Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);
startActivity(intent);
```

> Get Data From Activity:

```
String sessionId = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");
```

> Send Data From Fragment:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", "From Activity");

Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

> Get Data From Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("message");

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

> Send Data From Adapter to Fragment/Activity:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
               val bundle = Bundle()
               bundle.putString("id",data[position]?.id) 
               Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
               fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
 }
```

> Get Data From Adapter to Fragment/Activity:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("id");

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```